# Runtime Error 1004 - Unable to get the VLookup property of the WorksheetFunction class

Tags: excel, vlookup

this my code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim Username As String
Dim Password As String
Dim LookupPassword As Variant
Dim LookupPermission As Variant



Username = user.Value
Password = pass.Value

LookupPassword = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("Username", Range("UNT"), 3, 0)
LookupPermission = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("Username", Range("UNT"), 4, 0)

If IsError(LookupPassword) Then
MsgBox "Error"
Exit Sub

ElseIf Password <> LookupPassword Then
MsgBox "Error"
Exit Sub

ElseIf LookupPermission = "View" Then
Application.Visible = True

ElseIf LookupPermission = "Admin" Then
Application.Visible = True

ElseIf LookupPermission = "DataEntry" Then
Application.Visible = True

Else
MsgBox "Error"

End If


End Sub
```

i write code to lookup username and password and permission from table (UNT) but i have this error (runtime error 1004 unable to get vlookup)

Comment: That means that `VLOOKUP` failed to find a match. To check that using `IsError`, call it with `Application.VLookup`  (***not** with `Application.Worksheetfunction.Vlookup`*). The former will return the Excel error to your variable; the latter returns a VBA error message.

Comment: Also, just a heads up, remove the quotation marks from `"Username"` in your VLookup function, as this would be searching for the literal string "Username".

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways you can handle this:

**Option 1:** `WorksheetFunction.VLookup` with Error Handling

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim Username As String
    Dim LookupPassword As String

    Username = user.Value

    On Error Resume Next
    LookupPassword = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Username, Range("UNT"), 3, 0)

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    'proceed with code...

End Sub
```

**Option 2:** `Application.VLookup` with `IsError()` and Type `Variant`

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim Username As String
    Dim LookupPassword As Variant

    Username = user.Value

    LookupPassword = Application.VLookup(Username, Range("UNT"), 3, 0)

    If IsError(LookupPassword) Then
        MsgBox "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'proceed with code...

End Sub
```

**Note:** with this method, if you don't declare the lookup variable `As Variant`, it will fail with "*Run-time error '13': Type mismatch*".

**FYI:** you could use a single `Match` function, rather than multiple `VLookup` functions, to return each item using the `Range.Cells` method. For example:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'Validate username
    Dim rg As Range, Username As String, rowId As Variant
    Set rg = Range("UNT")
    Username = user.Value

    rowId = Application.Match(Username, rg.Columns(1), 0)

    If IsError(rowId) Then
        MsgBox "Username not found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

'Validate password
    Dim Password As String, LookupPassword As String
    Password = pass.Value
    LookupPassword = rg.Cells(rowId, 3).Value

    If StrComp(Password, LookupPassword, vbBinaryCompare) <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Incorrect password"
        Exit Sub
    End If

'Validate permission
    Dim LookupPermission As String
    LookupPermission = rg.Cells(rowId, 4).Value

    Select Case LookupPermission
        Case "View", "Admin", "DataEntry"
            Application.Visible = True
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Access denied"
    End Select

End Sub
```

I've also used `Select Case` here, rather than multiple `ElseIf` statements, to simplify the user permission validation process. Cheers!